# Java GUI Clear Panel To Blank Image

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Quick question, couldn't find a definitive answer from searching so I thought I'd ask here. In my code I set a JLabel to an image and I would like that image to clear and disappear after I perform a certain action such as clicking a button.

```
JLabel one = new JLabel(ruby); //ruby is a seperate ImageIcon already defined.
```

I'm not sure what the command to clear the panel is, an answer would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the label is already on the screen and you have a reference to the label you should be able to either call `remove(label)` on the parent container that contains the label or `label.setIcon(null)` if you want to reuse the label.  In either case, you may be required to call `revalidate` on the parent container

Comment: Just kidding it works, turns out last time I named the wrong variables. Thanks!

Comment: What does `revalidate` do ?

Comment: @JamesPoulson `revalidate` cause the container to re-layout it's contents and causes a `repaint` to be triggered